# Beginner's guide for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello friends i need a book/ tutorials for rails without using scoffold. All the books mentioned in the other questions are creating some depot application or etc using scaffold and then explaining things.
I believe in the thing that creating big depot is worthless when you are not getting anything. All of my frnds are suggesting me to go for [this pragmatic book](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition). look i understand the book is good but i m not getting the proper things. I got the logic cause i m good in php doctrine. asp.net c c++ so i m getting the things but i m not feeling confident. I want to have a another book. Can anybody suggest me some other books. I m saying this cause it really feels good when u create a simple form and insert the values in db and u can retreive those values and MOST IMP you can explain the whole logic of the that small form application instaed of that colorfull Depot application in which things are done with scaffold and u r not getting the thing and u are confused abt the real picture.

Comment: If you don't want to use scaffolding, you can generate the controller, the model and write everything by hand. Any good book will show you how to do it.

Comment: Scaffolding is to make your life easier. But you can always as Pablo says write everything by hand. All good books tell you how to go about it. But they always start with scaffolding. So have patience and read the book completely. In fact you can understand the juggling that happens between a Model-View-Controller better if you just dissect the scaffold. And that is how its explained in Learning Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails for Php developer is the book i was looking for.. Thnks to every1.

[Thinkvitamin](http://Thinkvitamin.com) has a paid video series for the ruby on rails. Awesome.

Another great (online) guide is: http://railsforzombies.org/

Answer (score 7):

There is no better resource online than the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). Truly amazing piece of work.

Another good online resource is the [Rails 3 Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) - highly recommended!

Comment: R they creating a application cause i m in favour of writing small small forms instead of one colorful app.. Cause things are more clear when u break the things...

Comment: No, they are not. The guides are autonomous and useful on their own. You don't need to read everything either.

Comment: @Bozhidar Batsov hey .. they are using  Scaffolding.. I just hate it.. WHy dont there is any tutorial in which we are doing things without  Scaffolding

Comment: In some of the tutorials they are, but most of them don't feature scaffolding. It's hard to teach view concepts with scaffolds. There are just a feature for the impatient to get them hooked.

Answer (score 5):

Latter take a look at best Rails screen casts at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)

Comment: +1 from me - nice tip. It's good to see that PeepCode has some free alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

AWDWR is the best. But if you want to go for some other book I suggest [Learning Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596518773).

Its simple and easy to understand. After that you can go ahead with AWDWR.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the building-a-depot part of Agile Web Development with Rails, what you can do is jump to the third part, "Working with the Rails Framework", and learn every part of Rails with a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

Another great (online) guide is:
http://railsforzombies.org/

You may print out the learning PDF for a quick overview at the beginning.